# Assign a keyboard shortcut to "Add a face..." action in iPhoto?

Tags: keyboard, photos.app

Is it possible to assign a keyboard shortcut to the "Add a face..." action in iPhoto? Preferably one that can be used outside of the Info view, so you can move quickly from viewing a photo to editing its info and adding a face?